# Contragredient of a cuspidal representation

Tags: representation-theory, locally-compact-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a nonarchimedean local field $F$. Let $\pi$ be an irreducible, cuspidal representation of $G$, with contragredient $\tilde{\pi}$. Then $\tilde{\pi}$ is cuspidal.

A character of $G$ is unramified if it is trivial on all compact subgroups of $G$. The group of unramified characters of $G$ acts on the set of isomorphism classes of irreducible, cuspidal $G$-representations. Under this action, is $\tilde{\pi} \sim \pi$?

Note: This question has now been asked at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295897/contragredient-of-a-cuspidal-representation).